# how to use URI templates to change path parameters in a URL in java

Tags: java, uri, uritemplate, url-template

I followed the tutorial available in [here](https://dzone.com/articles/using-uritemplate-change-path) for replacing path parameters with given values and ran the sample code which is given below

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String template = "http://example.com/name/{name}/age/{age}";
        UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate(template);
        String uri = "http://example.com/name/Bob/age/47";
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

        // Not this method returns false if the URI doesn't match, ignored
        // for the purposes of the this blog.
        uriTemplate.match(uri, parameters);
        System.out.println(parameters);
        parameters.put("name","Arnold");
        parameters.put("age","110");

        UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath(template);
        URI output = builder.build(parameters);
        System.out.println(output.toASCIIString());


    }
}
```

but when I compile the code it gives me this error

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The template variable 'age' has no value`

Please help me out to fix this, (may be my imports are causing the issue)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String template = "http://example.com/name/{name}/age/{age}";
    UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate(template);
    String uri = "http://example.com/name/Bob/age/47";
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    // Not this method returns false if the URI doesn't match, ignored
    // for the purposes of the this blog.
    uriTemplate.match(uri, parameters);
    System.out.println(parameters);
    parameters.put("name","Arnold");
    parameters.put("age","110");

    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath(template);
    // Use .buildFromMap()
    URI output = builder.buildFromMap(parameters);
    System.out.println(output.toASCIIString());

}
```

If you are using `.build` for filling the template, you have to provide the values one by one like `.build("Arnold", "110")`. In your case you want to use `.buildFromMap()` with your `parameters` map.